# plot line over boxplot using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have a pandas DataFrame with 16 columns corresponding years (2000 to 2015) and 12 lines with values for each month.

I'm trying plot a boxplot and a line with 2015 values in same fig in order to compare, using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel('hidro_ne.xlsx')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax1 = df[2015].plot(ax=ax, linewidth=2, legend='2015',color='red')
df.T.plot.box(yticks=range(0, 100, 5), ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```

In 2015 column I have data from January until September, but I get a shift line plot, from yline until september:

[image]

In fact the line should start at "Jan" and goes until "set", and not finish in "ago":

```
>>> df[2015]
Jan    16.41
Fev    18.34
Mar    23.52
Abr    27.40
Mai    26.96
Jun    25.34
Jul    22.49
Ago    18.38
Set    13.87
Out      NaN
Nov      NaN
Dez      NaN
```

I'm running the script using Python 3.4.3, pandas 1.7.0, over Windows 8.1.

How can I fix it?

Comment: And what values do you expect the line to show for those months if you don't have the data? The graph is showing precisely whay it should be showing, given the input data

Comment: df.plot starts the labelling at 0 and boxplot at 1 I think(which is annoying especially when the index is the same). Try `ax.plot(list(range(1,13)), df[2015].values)` for the line plot instead.

Comment: vmg, I do not have values to "Out", "Nov" and "Dez", but I have value to "Set" and it is not show on plot. In fact it is shifted.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you so much, pbreach.

It works to me.

I made:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('hidro_ne.xlsx')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(list(range(1,13)), df[2015].values, 'r', linewidth=2)
ax.legend(['2015'])
df.T.plot.box(yticks=range(0, 105, 5), ax=ax)
```

[image]