# Plot boxplot and line from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to reproduce this graph - a line plot with a boxplot at every point:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4JdH.png)

However, the line plot is always starting at the origin instead of at the first x tick:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w9bb.png)

I have collected my datastructure in a pandas file, with each column header the k_e (of the x axis), with the column being all of the datapoints.

I am plotting the mean of each column and the boxplot like so:

```
df = df.astype(float)

_, ax = plt.subplots()
df.mean().plot(ax = ax)
df.boxplot(showfliers=False, ax=ax)

plt.xlabel(r'$k_{e}$')
plt.ylabel('Test error rate')
plt.title(r'Accuracies with different $k_{e}$')

plt.show()
```

I have referred to the link below, and so am passing the 'ax' position but this does not help.

[plot line over boxplot using pandas DateFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578342/plot-line-over-boxplot-using-pandas-dateframe)

EDIT: Here is a minimal example:

test_errors_dict = dict()
    np.random.seed(40)

```
test_errors_dict[2] = np.random.rand(20)
test_errors_dict[3] = np.random.rand(20)
test_errors_dict[5] = np.random.rand(20)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=test_errors_dict)
df = df.astype(float)

_, ax = plt.subplots()
df.mean().plot(ax=ax)
df.boxplot(showfliers=False, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Result:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n92xW.png)

As shown in the above, the line plots do not align with the boxplot

Comment: Make sure to provide a [mcve], such that your problem becomes reproducible.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest done!

Comment: Ah ok, that is a similar issue than [this one](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11133).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boxes are at positions 1,2,3, while the plot is at positions 2,3,5. You may reindex the `mean` Series to also use the positions 1,2,3.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

test_errors_dict = dict()
np.random.seed(40)

test_errors_dict[2] = np.random.rand(20)
test_errors_dict[3] = np.random.rand(20)
test_errors_dict[5] = np.random.rand(20)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=test_errors_dict)
df = df.astype(float)

mean = df.mean()
mean.index = np.arange(1,len(mean)+1)

_, ax = plt.subplots()
mean.plot(ax=ax)
df.boxplot(showfliers=False, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]