# Aligning subplots in pyplot when using line plots over a boxplot

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot, subplot

I'm trying to overlay subplots for specific rows in my dataframe as line plots onto a box and whisker plot of the same data.
I'm trying to illustrate that my outliers come from two specific rows, where each row is a specific device I have data on.
The issue I have is that the subplots are offset by one 'unit' of the x axis label spacings.
I've tried `sharex=True` but this doesn't seem to work - I have a suspicion it might be to do with the rotation of the boxplot, but am stuck.
[The output plot with lines out by one 'tick' spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u6aY.png)
In the plot above the line plots should have all x values relate to each boxplot.
Does anyone have an idea what I should try to solve this?

Here's my code to get the plot above:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv("PlotData2.csv")
df_plot = df.iloc[:, 0:20]
line_plot1 = df_plot.iloc[1]
line_plot2 = df_plot.iloc[0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(-3.2, -1.6)

ax = df_plot.boxplot(grid = False, rot=90, showmeans=True, manage_ticks=True)
ax.set(ylabel ='Voltage (V)')
ax.invert_yaxis()
fig.tight_layout()
ax.plot(line_plot1)
ax.plot(line_plot2)
plt.figure()
```

Comment: Could you add some dummy test data to make your code reproducible? Could you add an image of the plot you got (StackOverflow will show it as a link, and after revision a moderator will change that to an inline image)?

Comment: Did you see [plot line over boxplot using pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578342/plot-line-over-boxplot-using-pandas-dataframe) and similar posts?  As pandas boxplots by default start at 1, you could add 1 to the x positions of the line.  Alternatively, you can use `boxplot(..., positions=...)` to set the x positions of the boxplot.  But without plot and without test data, it is unclear what is happening in your case.

Comment: I don't recall having it suggested as a possible solution, which was odd, but this solved it all - thanks for highlighting the post.